# How can I use this query with the query method (SQLiteDatabase.query)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The task I've been given is to write a query to return the number of orphaned rows. I have achieved this but another task is to then not use the rawQuery method to achieve the same result using the query method.

The issue is that I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables

The tables, there are 3 are

1. the parent table which has an _id column and a name column
2. the child table which has an _id column, a name column and a childtoparentlink column that is an integer that links to the parent table.
3. the friend table which has an _id column, a name column and a friendtochildlink column.

The SQL to create and to put rows into the tables, including some orphans is like

```
CREATE TABLE parent(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,parentname TEXT);
CREATE TABLE child(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,childname TEXT, childtoparentlink INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE friend(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,friendname TEXT, friendtochildlink INTEGER);
INSERT INTO parent VALUES(null,'Parent A');
INSERT INTO parent VALUES(null,'Parent B');
INSERT INTO child VALUES(null,'Child A',1);
INSERT INTO child VALUES(null,'Child B',2);
INSERT INTO child VALUES(null,'Child X',10); -- orphan
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(null,'Friend A',1);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(null,'Friend B',2);
INSERT INTO friend VALUES(null,'Friend X',100); -- orphan
```

The query that works and gives the right values when using rawQuery is

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT count() FROM child 
            LEFT JOIN parent ON child.childtoparentlink = parent._id 
        WHERE parent.parentname IS NULL
    ) AS child_mismatches,
    (
        SELECT count() FROM friend 
            LEFT JOIN child ON friend.friendtochildlink = child._id 
        WHERE child.childname IS NULL
    ) AS friend_mismatches
```

- I get two columns each with a value of 1 (as wanted).

My actual code is :-

```
public ArrayList<String> checkLinkIntegrity() {
    ArrayList<String> return_value = new ArrayList<>();
    String suffix = "_mismatches";
    String child_result_cl = TB_CHILD + suffix;
    String sq_child_mismatches = "(SELECT count() FROM " +
            TB_CHILD +
            " LEFT JOIN " + TB_PARENT +
            " ON " + TB_CHILD + "." + CL_CHILDTOPARENTLINK + " = " +
            TB_PARENT + "." + CL_PARENTID +
            " WHERE " + TB_PARENT + "." + CL_PARENTNAME + " IS NULL)" +
            " AS " + child_result_cl;
    String friend_result_cl = TB_FRIEND + suffix;
    String sq_friend_mismatches = "(SELECT count() FROM " +
            TB_FRIEND +
            " LEFT JOIN " + TB_CHILD +
            " ON " + TB_FRIEND + "." + CL_FRIENDTOCHILDLINK + " = " +
            TB_CHILD + "." + CL_CHILD_ID +
            " WHERE " + TB_CHILD + "." + CL_CHILDNAME + " IS NULL)" +
            " AS " + friend_result_cl;
    String full_query = "SELECT " + sq_child_mismatches + "," + sq_friend_mismatches;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor csr;
    Log.d("RAWQUERYSQL",full_query);
    csr = db.rawQuery(full_query,null);
    return_value.addAll(dumpCursorToStringArrayList(csr,"RAWQUERY"));

    // Fails invalid table
    csr = db.query(null,new String[]{sq_child_mismatches,sq_friend_mismatches},null,null,null,null,null);
    return_value.addAll(dumpCursorToStringArrayList(csr,"SECONDTRY"));
    csr.close();
    return return_value;
}
```

and the dumpCursortoStringArrayList method is :-

```
private ArrayList<String> dumpCursorToStringArrayList(Cursor csr, String tablename) {
    ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    int original_position = csr.getPosition();
    csr.moveToPosition(-1);
    rv.add("Table: " + tablename);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add("\tRow # " + String.valueOf(csr.getPosition() + 1));
        for (String column: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            rv.add("\t\tColumn: " + column + "\tvalue is: \t" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(column)));
        }
    }
    csr.moveToPosition(original_position);
    return rv;
}
```

I get the same error if I try "" instead of null e.g.

If I use only the rawQuery I get

```
04-22 07:07:33.914 6271-6271/s.q001 I/RESULTS: Table: RAWQUERY
04-22 07:07:33.914 6271-6271/s.q001 I/RESULTS:  Row # 1
04-22 07:07:33.914 6271-6271/s.q001 I/RESULTS:      Column: child_mismatches    value is:   1
04-22 07:07:33.914 6271-6271/s.q001 I/RESULTS:      Column: friend_mismatches   value is:   1
```

This is from using

```
    ArrayList<String> results = DBOpenHelper.checkLinkIntegrity();
    for (String s : results) {
        Log.i("RESULTS",s);
    }
```

How can I run the query with the query method instead of the rawQuery method, to get the better marks?

Comment: @forpas Oh, the tutor appears to think you can, so I don't think you are right.

Comment: See the answer I've posted, with a little consideration of what the query method does, it's a simple solution(s as there are at least 2 ways).

Comment: @forpas well both of the solutions MikeT gave work, so I am very lucky, although I don't think it was luck that mattered though.

Comment: @forpas I will ask but I know my tutor say a lot learning to tricks make understanding bettter is good learning and tutor said this about the extra marks for doing this. Tutor is very good and teaches us understanding well.

Comment: @forpas you not explain what is wrong, you only say it wrong. You can explain what is wrong and why not use a trick? What about Android says *If you know the query at compile time, you should always prefer Query since it validates the query at compile time and also generates more efficient code*?

Comment: @srolyat there is nothing wrong, it's not a trick, it's adhering more to the general recomendation that **rawQuery** should only be used when needed, due to the limitations and kudos on you finding part of why that is the general recommendation.

Comment: @srolyat additionally the convenience methods reduce the potential for simple errors as the majority of the SQL is built to strictly adhere to the correct syntax, so keywords clause order are well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the query method expects a table as it then generates SQL as per

```
SELECT your_columns FROM the_table;
```

As there is no table it issues the Invalid Table exception.

You have to provide something that will satisfy the **FROM** clause, it cannot be nothing.

You can get around this in a few ways, which I guess is what the homework is trying to get you to ascertain/explore.

## Fix 1

You could supply one of the tables that exist e.g. use

```
csr = db.query(null,new String[]{sq_child_mismatches,sq_friend_mismatches},null,null,null,null,null,"1");
```

- Note the 8th parameter, this **LIMIT**s the number of rows generated to one as there would be a row generated for each row in the *fake* table.

## Fix 2

or as FROM can be a subquery (see diagram) you could use a subquery e.g. one that you have
[image]

So you could use :-

```
    csr = db.query(
            sq_child_mismatches, //<<<<<<<<<< the fake subquery
            new String[]{
                    sq_child_mismatches,
                    sq_friend_mismatches
            },
            null    ,null,null,null,null
    );
```

- In this case, as the fake subquery returns a single row/result, there is no need for the **LIMIT** clause.

Comment: Let me try it out.

Comment: Thankyou, both worked and also so simple. Also many thanks more as I getting to understand so much more.